linphone-sdk fails set contact address to public ip when registering using natPolicy
linphone-sdk fails set contact address to public ip when registering using natPolicy
The fallowing is the code I am using it successfully registers but the IP in the contact header is incorrect.  This same stun server works with other clients. Do you have any clues?
private fun register(username: String, password: String, domain: String) {
        val natPolicy = core.createNatPolicy()
        natPolicy.isStunEnabled = true
        natPolicy.stunServer = "stun.gmx.net:3478"
        core.natPolicy = natPolicy

        val identity = Factory.instance().createAddress("sip:$username@$domain") ?: return
        val accountParams = core.createAccountParams()
        val authInfo = Factory.instance().createAuthInfo(username, null, password, null, null, domain)

        accountParams.identityAddress = identity
        val proxyAddress = Factory.instance().createAddress("sip:$domain")
        proxyAddress?.transport = TransportType.Udp
        accountParams.serverAddress = proxyAddress
        accountParams.isRegisterEnabled = true


        val account = core.createAccount(accountParams)

        core.addAuthInfo(authInfo)

        core.addAccount(account)
        core.defaultAccount = account
    }```

